# Passing Parameters in Racket

Tags: parameters, scheme, lisp, racket

I am working in Racket with no experience.

I am going to write what I wanted to write in C:

```
void function(int array[]){
    printf("%i total has been rolled from rolls %i and %i.\n", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
}
```

As you can see it is just a basic function that will print out the values of a list I want to pass in to my function. I do not know how to pass parameters (is this the correct terminology?) in Racket. I am trying to pass in a list with the format:
(sum num1 num2) or I can pass it in as ((sum) num1 num2) if that makes it easier.

This is my current function:

```
(define (throw-value) 
    (list (list(list-sum (dice-rolls))) (car(dice-rolls)) (car(dice-rolls))))
```

Where dice-rolls is my parameter list that I desire to use.

Any suggestions? Code segments would be GREAT!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the question of how to pass parameters in Racket - just declare them after the function's name, and be careful with the parentheses (there are several erroneous parentheses in your code). I believe you were aiming for something like this:

```
(define (throw-value dice-rolls)
  (list (list-sum dice-rolls) (car dice-rolls) (car dice-rolls)))
```

The above will return a list in the format `(sum num1 num2)`, be aware that `num1` and `num2` will be the same number, because in both cases you're taking the first element of the list. Now, for the rest of the question - in Racket, a direct translation of the C code in the question will look like this:

```
(define (function vec)
  (printf "~a total has been rolled from rolls ~a and ~a.~n"
          (vector-ref vec 0)
          (vector-ref vec 1)
          (vector-ref vec 2)))

(define vec (vector 1 2 3)) ; `vec` is a vector
(function vec)
=> 1 total has been rolled from rolls 2 and 3.
```

Although the linked list is the standard data structure in Lisp-based programming languages, whenever you need to efficiently access data given an index it's better to use a [vector](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html) as shown above. If for some reason you really have to use a list you can do so, albeit less efficiently (linked lists are not optimized for index-based access):

```
(define (function lst)
  (printf "~a total has been rolled from rolls ~a and ~a.~n"
          (list-ref lst 0)
          (list-ref lst 1)
          (list-ref lst 2)))

(define lst (list 1 2 3)) ; `lst` is a singly-linked list
(function lst)
=> 1 total has been rolled from rolls 2 and 3.
```

Comment: Thank you Oscar, this is huge!

Comment: As always, it was my pleasure ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using #!Racket and not Scheme, why not use [struct](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html?q=struct#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct%29%29)

```
(struct dice (total min max) #:transparent) 

(define (print-dice d)
  (printf "~a total has been rolled from rolls ~a and ~a.~n"
          (dice-total d)
          (dice-min d)
          (dice-max d)))

(print-dice (dice 10 2 6))
```